# New help finding blue color in image

Tags: image, colors

I need some help finding out what the color of the text in this image is: http://www.marcuswhelan.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/banner_lf11.png

To be precise, all I need is the blue color for the word, English. I've spent the last hour trying out different hexes but to no avail. I would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The top part is #04708d. The bottom part only gets darker and darker.

Answer (score 0):

The color code is #06708A

Resource used: http://imagecolorpicker.com/

Comment: I don't see how the answer can be one color given the fact that on my monitor I see a linear gradient.

Comment: You are right @rene, the url resource given here in the answer can give the different colors the image 'ENGLISH' word has if that helps the given problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems hard to get ther color because all answers show a different hex-value.

I have two, found with the color picker of Paint.net.
The top color: #05718D
The bottom color: #024456

I have this html and css to see if it resembles somewhat to the original picture:

**css**

```
div {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 128px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    #05718D 0%,
    #024456 100%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

**html**

```
<div>
    ENGLISH
</div>
```

and a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qynu8/) to play with it (in Chrome)

Comment: Thanks for the help man. I'll play around with it on Jsfiddle.